# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Necesito ayuda estoy haciendo una conexión de PHP con Mysql y me aparece que no se puede hacer.

Me da este error:

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061).

**Use:**

```html
<?php
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','prueba');

print_r($conexion);

if($conexion->connect_errno)
{
echo "no conexion";
}
else{
  echo "si conexion";
}
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para que te podamos ayudar, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/131574/edit), colocando el código de la conexión.

Comment: ¿El nombre de usuario y la contraseña que usas tienen permiso para conectarse? ¿La base de datos existe? ¿El servidor está instalado y corriendo en localhost? [Revisa lo que dice la documentación sobre tu error](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html), tendrás que hacer esas verificaciones.

Comment: Si soy nueva en esto, gracias por la bienvenida. Voy a revisar esos puntos.

Answer (score 0):

Para averiguar el error en especifico intenta colocar tu codigo dentro de un try y catch, algo como esto:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Fallo la conexion: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Conexion correcta";
```

Comment: Use este:<?php
$conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','prueba');

print_r($conexion);

if($conexion->connect_errno)
{
echo "no conexion";
}
else{
  echo "si conexion";
}
?>

Comment: Y me lanzo esto:mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => [client_info] => [client_version] => 50634 [connect_errno] => 2003 [connect_error] => Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) [errno] => [error] => [error_list] => [field_count] => [host_info] => [info] => [insert_id] => [server_info] => [server_version] => [stat] => [sqlstate] => [protocol_version] => [thread_id] => [warning_count] => )

Comment: Utiliza el print_r a la variable $conn->connect_error, en la parte del código del try catch eso te dirá cual es error mas especifico

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes acceso al servidor puedes intentar conectarte desde el cliente MySQL para corroborar si las credenciales son correctas y si no te mostrará mas errores, de lo contrario pon un codigo como el siguiente para atrapar el error.

```
  $conn = new mysqli();
  $conn->connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  if($conn->connect_error)
     die("Error: " . $conn->connect_error . " - Numero : " . $conn->connect_errno);
```

Comment: me muestra esto: mysqli Object ( [affected_rows] => [client_info] => [client_version] => 50634 [connect_errno] => 2003 [connect_error] => Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) [errno] => [error] => [error_list] => [field_count] => [host_info] => [info] => [insert_id] => [server_info] => [server_version] => [stat] => [sqlstate] => [protocol_version] => [thread_id] => [warning_count] => )